# Step Count always "0" using healthKit in swift

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, healthkit

I am trying to get last 7 days step count but it is always coming zero. But when I open the health app in iPhone then it is more than 3000 steps. Even I also added property Privacy - Health Share Usage Description and Privacy - Health Update Usage Description in .plist file. 
Here is my code

```
var healthScore = HKHealthStore()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Access Step Count
    let healthKitTypes: Set = [ HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)! ]
    // Check for Authorization
    healthScore.requestAuthorization(toShare: healthKitTypes, read: healthKitTypes) { (bool, error) in
        if (bool) {
            // Authorization Successful
            self.getSteps { (result) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let stepCount = String(Int(result))
                    self.stepLbl.text = String(stepCount)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func getSteps(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void){
    let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!

    let now = Date()
    let exactlySevenDaysAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -7), to: now)!
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: exactlySevenDaysAgo, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { (_, result, error) in
        var resultCount = 0.0

        guard let result = result else {
            print("\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription)) ")
            completion(resultCount)
            return
        }

        if let sum = result.sumQuantity() {
            resultCount = sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(resultCount)
        }
    }

    healthScore.execute(query)
}
```

In console I checked the dates are also correct now here's the screenshot[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS HealthKit today's step count is always 0 (but trailing days are OK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708829/ios-healthkit-todays-step-count-is-always-0-but-trailing-days-are-ok)

Comment: In my case it is zero for all days

Comment: You should check your dates carefully. I ran your code on my iPhone and it correctly returns the step count for the day selected (one week before today). Also, do you realize that you are returning from the getSteps function when you get the stats, so your statisticsupdatehandler can never be called.

Comment: @johnelemans thanks for the date and statisticsupdatehandler issue but still I am not getting the counts. I have updated my code.

Comment: as I said, the code you had worked correctly. try a date range instead of one day and see what you get.